# How can I modify my Node.js and React.js app to allow users to upload videos directly to my YouTube channel instead of their own using my API?"

Tags: node.js, oauth, google-api, youtube-api

In my Node.js and React.js app, I've implemented a feature that enables users to upload their videos to my YouTube channel when they click the upload button. I've developed an API for this purpose; however, it currently only allows users to upload videos to their own YouTube channels and not to mine. My objective is to have users upload videos exclusively to my YouTube channel, not their own. Thank you.where am i doing wrong in the below code?

```
const express = require( "express" );
const helpers = require( "../helpers/helpers" );
const fs= require( 'fs' );
const router = express.Router();
const youtube =require( "youtube-api" );
const credentials=require( '../../credentials.json' );
const Candidate = require( "../models/Candidate" );

router.post( "/upload-video/:candidate_id", async( req, res ) => {
    try {
        if ( !req.files || !req.files.video ) {
            return helpers.returnError( "Missing video file", res, 400 );
        }
        const { title, description } = req.body;
        const video = req.files.video;
        const candidateId=req.params.candidate_id;
        // console.log( req.files );
        const channelId = 'My_Channel_Id';
        const dir = `${__dirname}/videos/`;
  
        if ( !fs.existsSync( dir ) ) {
            fs.mkdirSync( dir, { recursive: true } );
        }
  
        await video.mv( `${dir}${video.name}` );
        const openModule = await import( 'open' );

        // Access the 'default' property if necessary
        const open = openModule.default || openModule;
        // console.log( video );
        open( oAuth.generateAuthUrl( {
            access_type:'offline',
            scope:'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload',
            state:JSON.stringify( {
                name:video.name,
                title, // Include title in state
                description,
                candidateId,channelId
            } )
        } ) );
        
        res.json( {
            error: false,
            msg: "Video uploaded successfully",
        } );
    } catch ( error ) {
        return helpers.returnError( "Error uploading video", res, 500 );
    }
} );


router.get( '/oauth2callback',( req,res )=>{
    console.log( "hiii" );
    const { name,title,description,candidateId ,channelId }=JSON.parse( req.query.state );

    console.log( name,title,description,"name" );
    fs.exists( `${__dirname}/videos/${name}`,( e )=>{
        if( e ){
            oAuth.getToken( req.query.code,( err,tokens )=>{
                if( err ){
                    console.log( err );
                    return;
                }
                oAuth.setCredentials( tokens );
                youtube.videos.insert( {
                    resource:{
                        snippet:{ title,description , channelId },
                        status:{ privacyStatus:'public' }
                    },
                    part:'snippet,status',
                    media:{
                        body:fs.createReadStream( `${__dirname}/videos/${name}` )
                    }
                },async( err,data )=>{
                    
                    if( err ) throw err;
                    console.log( data.data.id );
                    const youtubeLink=`https://youtu.be/${data.data.id}`;
                    
                    const candidate= await  Candidate.update(
                        { video_profile: youtubeLink }, // Set the new value for the videoProfile column
                        { where: { id: candidateId } } // Find the candidate by id
                    );
                    
                    res.redirect( `http://localhost:3000/candidates/${candidateId}` );

                    // Video uploaded successfully, now delete the file
                    fs.unlink( `${__dirname}/videos/${name}`, ( err ) => {
                        if ( err ) {
                            console.error( "Error deleting video file:", err );
                        } else {
                            console.log( "Video file deleted successfully" );
                        }
                    } );
                    
                    
                } );
            } );
        }
    } );
    
} );

const oAuth=youtube.authenticate( {
    type:'oauth',
    client_id:credentials.web.client_id,
    client_secret:credentials.web.client_secret ,
    redirect_url:credentials.web.redirect_uris[0]
} );

module.exports=router;
```

Comment: Users should not log in at all. You should hardcode your credentials somewhere and login automatically